# Microsoft Graph API update user authentication method - Access Denied

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating an application in Azure AD as a daemon to get user phone
authentication methods using the python msal library and calling the following following endpoint `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id | UPN}/authentication/phoneMethods` but i get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Request Authorization failed",
    "innerError": {
      "message": "Request Authorization failed",
      "date": "2020-11-19T19:26:28",
      "request-id": "11975e07-ee6b-4bd2-9a74-7c175c5da560",
      "client-request-id": "11975e07-ee6b-4bd2-9a74-7c175c5da560"
    }
  }
}
```

My app has the required application permissions to get the info i'm looking for, which are `UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All` and `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` and it already works with different end points such as `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id | UPN}`, this is the code i'm using in order to get the access token required and call the graph api

```
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal


config = {
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_NAME",
    "client_id": "APP_ID",
    "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    "secret": "APP_SECRET",
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{USER_ID}/authentication/phoneMethods"
}

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential=config["secret"],
    )

result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=None)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    graph_data = requests.get(
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, ).json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

i tried to do the same thing using curl or postman and i get the exact same error, so i'm guessing it's an access token issue maybe ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) call does not support **application permissions**. You need to grant **delegated permissions** to the application, and then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain the token.

[image]
[image]